# multiple event listeners using addeventListener to the same event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I type this code to the browser console:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", () => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(1));
    console.log(2);
}, false);

document.body.addEventListener("click", () => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(3));
    console.log(4);
}, false);
```

These two event listeners listen the click event and print numbers.

then I wrote a line to execute this statement:

```js
document.body.click();
```

Meets my expectations, the result is:

```js
2
4
1
3
```

But then, I click the screen, the event callbacks are triggered with this result:

```js
2
1
4
3
```

Why does clicking on the screen and executing the `body.click()` manually make different results?